# Can you install and configure MariaDB through ansible without root privileges?

Tags: mysql, ansible, mariadb

I'm trying to install adn configure Mariadb on a target machine through it's binary tarball using ansible and without having root privileges.

Most of the ansible roles on galaxy use yum or another installer to install the packages but I have to do it through the binary tarball. The configuration in these roles also creates a root user to create the other listed users and db's. Is there a way to install and configure mariadb through an ansible role without these privileges and using the tarball?

So far, I have downloaded the and unarchived the tarball but I've been unable to install or run mariadb as a non-root user. I'm wondering is this possible?

Any help or a referral to a role would be appreciated.

Comment: you did not show us what have you tried, try to follow this link on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask